# Variable-length lookbehind compiles if repetition is in parentheses. Why?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

### Problem

PHP uses the [PCRE](http://pcre.org) regex library, which does not support repetition in lookbehinds.

If repetition is in the lookbehind (e.g., `(?<=\d+)`), PHP will normally issue a warning like this:

> Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 7 in lookbehind.php on line 10

However, I have found a case where compilation does not fail when I think it should.

These fail to compile, as expected:

- `/(?<=X*)a/`
- `/(?<=X+)a/`
- `/(?<=(X)*)a/`

However, `/(?<=(X)+)a/` does compile. This should be functionally equivalent to `/(?<=(X){1,})a/`, which also compiles. On the other hand, if I actually add an upper bound to that range
(e.g., `/(?<=(X){1,2})a/`), that fails to compile. I think `/(?<=(X)+)a/` and `/(?<=(X){1,})a/` should also fail to compile, but they do not. Why not?

### Experimentation

Here's some code:

```php
$str = 'aXaaXXaaaXXXaaaa';

$regex = '/(?<=((?:X)+))a+/';

preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE|PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
```

I've complicated the pattern slightly to add a capturing group around the multiple `X`s. Here are my results:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [0] => aa
                    [1] => 2
                )
            [1] => Array (
                    [0] => X
                    [1] => 1
                )
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [0] => aaa
                    [1] => 6
                )
            [1] => Array (
                    [0] => X
                    [1] => 5
                )
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [0] => aaaa
                    [1] => 12
                )
            [1] => Array (
                    [0] => X
                    [1] => 11
                )
        )
)
```

It clearly matches the `a`s that follow `X`s, which is correct. However, subpattern 1 appears to only match one `X`, not all of them. If I add an `a` at the beginning of the lookbehind so that it must find all the `X`s in between, here are my results:

```php
$regex = '/(?<=(a(?:X)+))a+/';
```

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [0] => aa
                    [1] => 2
                )
            [1] => Array (
                    [0] => aX
                    [1] => 0
                )
        )
)
```

It only matches once (where there is only one `X`). Effectively, `(X)+` and `(X){1,}` are being reduced to `(X){1}` (which is allowable due to its fixed length).

### Conclusion

I hate to cry, "Bug!" as soon as I find something that doesn't do what I expect, but it sure seems like one. The pattern isn't rejected like I expect, and then it doesn't behave as I would expect it to even if it were a valid pattern.

So I ask:

- Is there a valid reason why it should behave this way?
- Why does this apply to `+` but not `*`?
- Why do parentheses matter:  `X+` fails; `(X)+` is allowed ?

Any insight is most appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/ is probably the place for this.

Comment: @vascowhite Well, yeah. The point of this question is to ask before I submit it if it's indeed a bug or just my lack of knowledge.

Comment: I would say that you've done enough testing and research to be reasonably confident that you've found a bug. If it isn't it will be closed as such with an explanation from the guys that wrote/maintain the software. Either way you get resolution much faster than you probably will here. I would say, submit it. You've already done a lot of work and this is the meat of an excellent bug report.

Comment: It's definitely a bug. Also [the PCRE bug repository](http://bugs.exim.org/buglist.cgi?product=PCRE&bug_status=NEW&bug_status=ASSIGNED&bug_status=REOPENED) could be appropriate if the bug is reproducible in the latest PCRE version.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a PHP bug. If it is a bug (and it does look like one) it is a PCRE bug and should be reported there. However, check the PCRE version in `phpinfo()` and compare it with the latest version. If it is not up-to-date try running the same regexes directly in the latest PCRE before posting a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

PCRE version 8.32-RC1 2012-08-08

re> /(?<=(X)+)a/
Failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length at offset 8
  re>

Probably was a bug. Please update to the latest PCRE.

Btw, you can use \K to create unlimited backreferences.

Comment: So it has since been submitted and fixed? Where did you find this information? I haven't found the bug report or 8.32-RC1 changelog.